# Генерация таблицы html на основе запроса из базы данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть sql запрос:

> `$sql=('SELECT channel.name_channel, channel.image_channel, tv_programm.start_time, telecast.name_telecast FROM channel INNER JOIN (telecast INNER JOIN tv_programm ON telecast.id_telecast=tv_programm.id_telecast) ON channel.id_channel=tv_programm.id_channel ORDER BY tv_programm.id_channel;`

Есть массив в php:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name_channel] => Первый
            [image_channel] => images/logo_channels/P1-1.png
            [start_time] => 2014-12-26 07:00:00
            [name_telecast] => От праздника к празднику
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name_channel] => Первый
            [image_channel] => images/logo_channels/P1-1.png
            [start_time] => 2014-12-26 08:00:00
            [name_telecast] => "V" значит Вендетта
        )
```

Нужно сгенерировать вот такие таблицы:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>logo</td>
      <td>name_channel</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>start_time</td>
      <td>name_telecast</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>start_time</td>
      <td>name_telecast</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>start_time</td>
      <td>name_telecast</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Вид таблицы в phpmyadmin:

[image]

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Таблицы красивые, код на первый взгляд верный, автор молодец.

Comment: Если Вы совсем не знаете, как это сделать, значит Вам это делать рановато. Вернитесь назад, почитайте уроки, погуглите. Я в своё время учился на php.su

Answer (score 1):

Самый "простой" путь - сгенерировать на  backend содержимое HTML php-скриптом, вот [пример реализации](http://site-on.net/create/php/10-html-table-php) подобного. Также есть готовые php-классы для отрисовки таблиц.

Можно использовать Smarty.

Однако лучше представление данных  вынести во frontend, то есть передать данные из backend во frontend в форме JSON, и реализовать  логику отрисовки таблицы с помощью javascript например. В этом случае есть готовые библиотеки для отрисовки таблиц, например плагин [dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/) для jquery. Или можно целый js-фреймворк использовать, если эта задача - капля в море, и в выбранном фреймворке много нужной функциональности. Также стоит это реализовать асинхронно, т.е. чтобы таблица отрисовывалась построчно, а не вешала браузер во время отрисовки целиком.

Вам стоит определиться, какой путь избрать, попробовать написать код, и в случае затруднений, не решившихся гуглением - запостить код с конкретным вопросом. Пока ваш вопрос выглядит слишком общим, примерно как "напишите за меня код, который будет делать Х".